# bitmap interpolation

Tags: c#, algorithm, image, image-processing

interpolation of bitmap:
I have bitmap of 16*16, i want to increase the size of the bitmap to 160*160, which is best interpolation type that can be suited.

Comment: Are you asking a question? What have you tried? Can you post your code samples and explain where you are having difficulties?

Comment: i have rectangle grid of size 160*160mm, each cell is filled with one color, this rectangle grid is represented by a bitmap, now i want to have smooth image, i have implemented the cubic spline for interpolating so that i can get a smooth image. I wanted to know whether cubic spline is the right algorithm for the interpolation

Comment: bear in mind that almost every pixel will be an interpolated one, unless the origianl bitmap is very simple the results may well look awful with any interpolation algo, you may be better off redrawing it at the larger size

Answer (score 1):

- [Bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) (cubic spline) blurs area and because of that destroys edges.
- [Nearest neighbour interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_interpolation) preserves edges, but introduces pixelation.

So best interpolation of bitmap would be hybrid algorithm of those two above - such as [2xSal / Eagle and such](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms).

**EDIT:** Bicubic interpolation [JAVA example code](http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic).

Good luck.

Comment: little confused with bicubic interpolation , in the Wikipedia it is mentioned that bicubic intepolation can be implemented using cubic spline , cubic convultion, how to extend this algorithms for bitmap interpolation - that is for 2d interpolation

Comment: @Ramesh: though I have not used it myself, I know that there is support in the framework for these interpolation techniques. If you don't specifically want to implement it yourself, look it up...

Answer (score 0):

Um, this is a horrendously bad idea no matter which way you look at it -  you're basically increasing the size of the bitmap by an order of magnitude, but you're not adding any new data - regardless of whether you use a polynomial, linear, or simple copy mechanism the result is going to show either extreme pixelation, extreme blurring, or some mixture of the two.

In general, these algorithms work much better for reducing the size of bitmap images and maintaining overall image integrity, blowing an image up by an order of magnitude is going to be ugly, no matter what you do -  the bottom line is that the original information is now dwarfed by the information the interpolater 'made up'